# Mvvmcross MvvmCross.Plugin.DownloadCache 4.1.5 for Xamarin Android

Tags: c, xamarin, mvvmcross

Nuget package

and manually nuget  `System.Collections.Immutable v1.1.36`

Deploy with Error as follows

> System.MissingMethodException: Method 'Array.Empty' not found.

Comment: Try nuget both package from .Core project , no lucky yet

Comment: '/system/lib/libc.so'.
05-20 15:35:46.099 D/Mono    ( 4555): DllImport loaded library '/system/lib/libc.so'.
05-20 15:35:46.099 D/Mono    ( 4555): DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/libc.so' ('/system/lib/libc.so').
05-20 15:35:46.099 D/Mono    ( 4555): Searching for 'gettid'.
05-20 15:35:46.099 D/Mono    ( 4555): Probing 'gettid'.
05-20 15:35:46.099 D/Mono    ( 4555): Found as 'gettid'.
Unhandled Exception:

System.MissingMethodException: Method 'Array.Empty' not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More people are reporting this bug. There is an issue filed on the github page, please check: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/1330

Comment: Thanks , I know where to reports now.